# visual studio issue pulling in web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

I am using VS2010, and I want to consume a webservice that was given to me

https://www.###################/pinManagement.cfc?wsdl
I have done this many times before but for some reason this one i cant get right

1. right click, add solution
2. add service reference
3. past in url, give a namespace and voila

This pulls in fine, but for some reason a bunch of objects in the wsdl are being left off, namely all the request/response objects. the methods are there, but nothing else.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use them in code?

Comment: nope. i have used the object browser also. nothing.... if i use soapui o do see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i solved it. thanks to Ian for the steps to see my error.

i got the solution from this site
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/51babae5-26e5-4405-b03c-4301710854c0/

but ill repost the steps below incase the link dies

In Visual studio:
1.       Click on "Show All Files" in the solution explorer

1. Open the file named "Reference.svcmap" in your service reference
2. Set the option UseSerializerForFaults to false in "Reference.svcmap" and save it (please don't update the service reference, apparently doing so will reset the option to true)
3. Open the Reference.cs and you should see the operations generated

Comment: This also works for Visual Studio 2013, as I just encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your web service select:

**Configure Service Reference=>Un-check reuse types in referenced assemblies**

See if that helps

**EDIT ::**

[image]

Comment: thanks, but didnt work. same results as before. floadcc doesnt accept a request object, and doesnt output a response object

Comment: none. are you able to pull the service in? it's publicly available

Comment: yes sure, thats the same spot i am at. but the floadpinba method then has a fDeletePinBARequest object as it's input paramater. yours (like mine) doesnt require it

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a proxy using the XmlSerializer. You can do that by running svcutil from the command line and then pulling the generated .cs and .config files into your project:

```
svcutil /serializer:XmlSerializer https://www.example.com/Collections/1x0x0/pinManagement.cfc?wsdl
```

Any errors that you get from svcutil will probably help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: clever. there are issues! this is what i get:   Warning: Fault named CFCInvocationException in operation fUpdatePinBA cannot be imported. Unsupported WSDL, the fault message part must reference an element. This fault message does not reference an element. If you have edit access to the WSDL document, you can fix the problem by referencing a schema element using the 'element' attribute.

Comment: got it. thanks for your tip. helped me to google the answer. ill post the answer above